# Добавление большого количества изображений во ViewPager

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Мне необходимо загружать большое количество элементов во ViewPager (это может быть несколько тысяч изображений). Так как пытаться загрузить все изображения за 1 раз это плохая идея, поэтому хотел бы узнать, есть ли готовое решение для этой проблемы ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: RecycleView ...............

Comment: Читайте про пагинацию, поможет))

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с большим количеством данных можно воспользоваться библиотекой из Android Jetpack "paging" - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.
Можно подсмотреть пример работы с ней в кодлабах - https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0